# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined in ckeditor when click on locationmap icon from toolbar

Tags: ckeditor

I am having below error in chrome when i click on locationmap icon from toolbar.

Can anybody have a solution ?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined
contents.elements.children.setup
(anonymous function) ckeditor.js:538
CKEDITOR.dialog.foreach ckeditor.js:537
CKEDITOR.dialog.setupContent ckeditor.js:538
(anonymous function) ckeditor.js:1078
j ckeditor.js:10
CKEDITOR.event.CKEDITOR.event.fire ckeditor.js:12
(anonymous function) ckeditor.js:536
(anonymous function)
```

And in Firefox below error when click on locationmap icon form toolbar.

> `TypeError: url[1] is undefined`   in locationmap.js?t=F0RD

Comment: have you tried define the **ckeditor base path**?? check this link http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_basepath

Comment: yes i tried but no effect. Still same error is coming.

Comment: I presume "locationmap" is some custom or 3rd party plugin. You should report this issue to its author because it's unlikely that someone here will know what's the problem with it. It's not even a valid SO question, because it lacks necessary information and it falls into "why isn't it working" category.